# Flask-Login: KeyError: 'security' when trying to call login_user

Tags: python-2.7, flask, flask-login, flask-security

I have the following code that logs in a user on my Flask application:

```
@app.route('/login', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('login.html')

    db = get_db()
    member = member_from_phone(request.form['phone_number'])
    member_obj = Member(member)

    if member is None:
        g.result = json.dumps({'head' : 200, 'body' : "invalid phone" })
        return 'no member...'
    elif request.form['password'] == member['password']:
        login_user(member_obj)
        return 'login successful'
    else:
        return 'login failed'
    return home_page()
```

However it throws a KeyError: 'security' when I try log in:

```
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask_security/utils.py", line 64, in login_user
    if _security.trackable:
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 338, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 297, in _get_current_object
    return self.__local()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask_security/utils.py", line 35, in <lambda>
    _security = LocalProxy(lambda: current_app.extensions['security'])
KeyError: 'security' when trying to call login_user
```

I have no idea what's going on, I think I might need to fix my flask configuration but I don't know how.

Comment: Are you properly creating the `user_datastore` and then initializing Flask-Security with `Security(app, user_datastore)`? [docs](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/quickstart.html)

Comment: You have only provided a single view function. Can you provide at least how you configure the app with Flask-Login and/or Flask-Security?